# Reading a 3-dimensional array from an Excel (IBM ILOG CPLEX)

Tags: arrays, excel, cplex, ilog

Let's say I have an excel workbook with two tabs. Both tabs contain a 2-dimensional matrix like

```
# 1st tab       # 2nd tab
1 1 1           1 1 1
1 1 1           1 1 1
1 1 1           1 1 1
```

How can I get those two tabs in a 3-dimensional array in IBM ILOG? The official IBM support page cannot find the topic [Reading a 3-dimensional array from an Excel](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21401340) anymore. This is a dead link. May anyone help me with this? It should be usable like this `arrayExample`. Not a tuple or anything else than an array.

```
int arrayExample[i][j][s] = [[[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]], [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]];
```

Comment: That link worked for me just now. Maybe try again, or with a different browser, or after clearing your cache.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still can't access that link, here is the information from that technote:

> Answer:
>
> Use an intermediate array (1 or 2 dimensions) to
>   read all the data, by calling the instruction SheetRead(). Then
>   initialize your 3-dimensional array:
>
> The model file (.mod):

```
int nbMonths = ...;
int nbProducts = ...;
int nbLevels = ...;
```

> // If the data elements are organized in columns

```
int nb1[1..nbMonths*nbProducts*nbLevels] = ...;
int nbArray[m in 1..nbMonths, p in 1..nbProducts,s in1..nbLevels]= nb1[s+nbLevels*(p-1)+nbProducts*nbLevels*(m-1)];
```

> // If the data elements are in a 2-dimensional array

```
int nb2[1..nbMonths, 1..nbProducts*nbLevels] = ...;
int nbArray2[m in 1..nbMonths, p in 1..nbProducts,s in 1..nbLevels] =  nb2[m,s+nbLevels*(p-1)];
```

> The data file (.dat)

```
SheetConnection sheetInput("3DimArray.xls", 0);
nb1 from SheetRead(sheetInput,"data!D2:D13");
nb2 from SheetRead(sheetInput,"data!B17:G18");
```

> Note: Data in spreadsheets and database tables are usually
>   2-dimensional. So 3-dimensional arrays cannot be stored in
>   spreadsheets or database tables natively.